# Practical differences between 2 class of the same size whose members are all bitflags

Tags: c++

Generally speaking, in C++, a class' size is the aggregate size of its members, including any base class members.

What are the practical differences between 2 classes defined like so, whose members all represent bitflags:

```
class A { // 16 bytes
    uint64_t x;
    uint64_t y;
};

class B { // 16 bytes
    uint64_t x;
    uint32_t y;
    uint16_t z;
    uint8_t  r;
    uint8_t  s;
};
```

**The ones that I can think of are:**

- B's data can be accessed more granularly, without having to do bitwise operations. For example, to access the equivalent of B::r in A, you would have to do something like:

  ```
  (a.y & 0xFF00) >> 8; // b.r
  ```
- Semantically, different members mean that the data of those members pertain to different concepts of the class. i.e: 'age' is a different concept than 'length'.

**Things that I believe are the same on both classes:**

- Memory layout.

**Things that I don't know:**

- How CPU cache is affected between both classes.
- Any speed difference, whatsoever, when performing bitwise operations on the members of those 2 classes.

Comment: Same memory layout is not guaranteed. Padding.

Comment: If you want something closer to assurance that they're laid out the same, consider something like: `class C { uint64_t x; uint64_t y : 32; uint64_t z : 16; uint64_t r : 8; uint64_t s : 8; };` This tells the compiler you want to access `y`, `z`, `r` and `s` as bit fields stored in a `uint64_t`, instead of as separately allocated variables. This doesn't guarantee anything, but it at least *tells* the compiler (and anybody else who reads the code) your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your questions heavily depend on the target platform, particularly its Application Binary Interface (ABI).  You can examine the X86-64 System V ABI here (Windows has a different ABI):

https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI

The ABI governs structure layout (among many other things) and as Sam mentioned, the layout of the two structures is not guaranteed to be the same.  For X86-64 they will happen to be the same, but for some other target, padding between fields could be introduced.

How the fields themselves are accessed also depends on the target architecture, namely the instructions available to do loads and stores.  Many machines exist which do not directly support byte-sized memory access, so fields r and s would be accessed via bit-shifting after a wider load.  It is the compiler's responsiblity to generate the correct code for a field access operation.

It's also concievable that some machine might have registers wide enough to hold the entire struct, meaning accessing any fields would require some bit twiddling.  Indeed, the X86-64 ABI specifies function call semantics that would pass either struct in two registers to the callee, which would then need to extract the data, likely pushing it on the stack for access within the function.

For almost all real-world applications, these details don't matter much and either struct layout will work fine.  From a programmer's point of view, the second would be preferable assuming that the fields correspond to logical concepts within the program.  It's much easier to read simple field accesses than bit-shifts and masks of fields accesses.

Of course, certain applications care very much about layout, for performance, space concerns or interoperability between systems.